# Vim script: check if the cursor is on the current word

Tags: vim

For example in this situation:

```
function_call(arg1, arg2);
                  ^Cursor is here
```

calling `expand('<cword>')` will return "arg2".
I need to filter out these cases, when cursor is on left from the current word's position.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative using the position for (next) `<cword>` is:
(according to a comment by OP he want to know, perhaps the question should be updated with that request)

```
let cInd = strridx(getline('.'), expand("<cword>"), col('.') - 1)
let isOnKeyword = (cInd >= 0 && (cInd + strlen(expand("<cword>"))) >= (col('.') - 1))
```

The second part is needed if the next `<cword>` is also in an earlier position on the current line, in your example if the string `arg2` should have been in the line also somewhere before the `,`, that is hypothetical but should be considered.
Note that it's `strridx` **not** `stridx`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by checking whether the cursor currently is on a keyword character:

```
let isOnKeyword = matchstr(getline('.'), '\%'.col('.').'c.') =~# '\k'
```

Comment: Great, thanks!!!
BTW: there is much simpler way to get current character  
`getline('.')[col('.')-1] =~# '\k'`

Comment: I was thinking to get current word's starting position and compare it with the cursor position, but didn't find a way to do it. So if anyone knows how to get <cword>'s start position please share it, it might be helpful in the future. Thanks :)

Comment: Your simpler way doesn't work with multi-byte characters (e.g. `ä` in UTF-8).